# How to Install Mono 2.4 from Source on Fedora 11

Tags: fedora, mono

Please could someone give me instructions on how to install Mono 2.4 & mod_mono & xsp from source on Fedora 11

So that I can run ASP.NET

Thanks

Lucifer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to install again mono, mod_mono, xsp form distribution, then
from source using 2.2, 2.4 and svn.

The problem is with the kernel 2.6.24-23-xen present on both servers. It
has a bug that has been fixed in the following versions . The problem is
the 64bit XEN kernel does not honour the MAP_32BIT flag.

And to add insult to injury, i cannot upgrade the kernels because it's a
VPS and i cannot install kernels.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=217869) Mono is installed by default on Fedora 11. I don't have it installed yet to play with it and confirm.

If it is not there, you would just need to do: 
**yum install mono** and 
**yum install mod_mono**

Comment: +1 - http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=30 suggests that the packages for Mono in F11 are 2.4.